Игнорит FSM aiogram 3
    @hand_callback.callback_query(F.data == 'add_user')
async def add_user(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await callback.message.answer('Введите user_id пользователя')
    await state.set_state(User.user_id)


@hand_callback.message(User.user_id)
async def user_id_received(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    user_id = message.text
    assistant.add_user(user_id, None)  # Assuming assistant is defined
    await state.clear()
    await message.answer('Пользователь успешно добавлен ')

оно не добавляет пользователя пытался чтоб он доходил до конца но он не доходит

Я разобрался короч, её просто ловил другой обработчик, обработчик который ловит любой текст (F.text)
